# Jasny Bootstrap rowlink Modal invocation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

i just found out that there was an extension to bootstrap when i am trying to find something like `.row-link`so when i implemented it on my table, i can't seem to invoke a modal on when i click on each row. the modal in boostrap won't be invoke. I really can't trace why cuz when i debugged (using firebug) the page, the **td tag** where i put my **a tag**, my **a tag** link can't be seen. the one that is displayed is only the value of  . 
e.g `<a> some link </a>`

**some link** is the only thing i see on firebug, usually when i debug i see all the html tag like so `<a href="some link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="some taget"> click me </a>`
but i really don't know why i can't invoke a modal using row-link

**Again, my goal when i click 1 row a modal box appears**

here is my code snippet

```
<table>
   <thead>
        // some headers
   </thead>
   <tbody data-provides="rowlink">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal">Click me</a> </td>
        <td>/*some data*/</td>
        <td>/*some data*/</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div id="myModal" /*some legit modal attr please see bootstrap site i just copied them*/>
    <div>
        MODAL HEADER
    </div>

    <div>
        MODAL BODY
    <div>

    <div>
        MODAL FOOTER
    <div>
</div>
```

WHEN I TRIED THIS ONE, NOTE THAT THIS link is outside the **table html tag**

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-targe="modal">Click me</a>
```

Anyone knows how to implement modal view inside row-link please do share

Comment: `href="#"` should be `href="#myModal"`

Comment: opps edited it.. acutally dats wat i did, sorry for the type, still the problem persist

Comment: actually that one below already works but the sad thing is it isn't row-link its just outside the table

Comment: Ok [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyUEb/). I added #myModal to href inside `<a>` and classes `"modal fade hide"` to modal.

Comment: actually this works fine when your invoking link is outside the rowlink data attribute got no problem with that, my problem is when i put it inside a rowlink table.. see my edit above

Comment: i can't event find the <a> </a> tags when i looked at firebug

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vyUEb/1/). The markup I copied from their site works (If you click on Action). It seems they expect <a> tag in all columns also it expects last column to be action link. Not sure though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29060/discussion-between-lemoncodes-and-anpsmn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check this [link](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-rowlink.js), the below code takes the href from the link and changes the window.location to href on click of row and hence it's expecting an URL.

```
var href = link.attr('href')

$(this).find('td').not('.nolink').click(function() {
   window.location = href;
})
```

Also the `<a>` tag being stripped is also mentioned in their code.

```
link.replaceWith(link.html())
```

A solution to tackle this is to manually write a script where in you target the row which will have modal and add the required attribute to the row. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyUEb/5/). Here I have given a class `.rowlink-modal` to the tr which one would want to be clickable and target that class in script and add data attributes.

```
$('.rowlink-modal').each(function(){
 $(this)
   .attr('data-toggle','modal')
   .attr('data-target','#myModal');
});
```

The 'Action' link if clicked will open modal2 and when you click the whole row the first modal is opened.

Comment: yo dude sorry for a very late update, both you and the one who made the jasny extensions made some point, he put explicitly the data-attr while you used js. hmm both of you are right.. i guess u ans first i'll choose this one

Answer (score 3):

## Boostrap 3

This works out of the box with Bootstrap 3.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Modals</a></td>
            <td>some text</td>
            <td class="rowlink-skip"><a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">Action</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## Bootstrap 2

For now rowlink can't be used to trigger JavaScript events which would take place when clicking the link. It will only open URLs using `location.href`. This will be fixed in the future.

However, in this case it isn't needed to use rowlink. You can add `data-toggle="modal"` to each `tr` and add a property `data-target` instead of using `href`.

To get the rowlink style however effect, add the `rowlink` class to the `tr`.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rowlink" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
            <td>Modals</td>
            <td>some text</td>
            <td class="nolink"><a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">Action</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/vyUEb/6/)

Comment: good day sir, yes i get it, someone already did some js workaround but both your answer are the same, only thing is that he used js to put the data-attr while yours is explictly written on the trs.. i'll choose this cuz he was the one who answered first. tnx anyways sir.

Comment: This example is for Bootstrap 2. I'll add a Bootstrap 3 example.